# java.security.InvalidKeyException: No installed provider supports this key: (null) while verifying signed pdf

Tags: java, cryptography, itext, digital-signature

**i am getting this exception on**

```
PdfPKCS7 pkcs7 = fields.verifySignature(name);
```

**this is the complete code**

```
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.AcroFields;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.PdfPKCS7;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class NewClass {

    public static void main(String arg[])
            throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        String path = "C:/Akshay/output.pdf";
        System.out.println(path);
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(path);
        AcroFields fields = reader.getAcroFields();
        ArrayList<String> names = fields.getSignatureNames();
        for (String name : names) {
            System.out.println("===== " + name + " =====");
            verifySignature(fields, name);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void verifySignature(AcroFields fields, String name)
            throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
        System.out.println("Signature covers whole document: "
                + fields.signatureCoversWholeDocument(name));
        System.out.println("Document revision: " + fields.getRevision(name)
                + " of " + fields.getTotalRevisions());
        PdfPKCS7 pkcs7 = fields.verifySignature(name);
        System.out.println("Integrity check OK? " + pkcs7.verify());

    }

}
```

**jar used :**

1. itextpdf-5.5.13.jar
2. bcprov-jdk14-1.49.jar

Comment: You need to register the bc provider with `java.security.Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());`.

Comment: In case the answer above did not fix your issue, would it be possible to have some details on the key (type, length, signature method used) that you're signing with?

Comment: above solution does work.. thank you @ Paulo Soares

Answer (score 4):

You should add a provider like BouncyCastle and add in the call like below example:

Add first the provider

```
Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
```

then add the provider to get the signature

```
PdfPKCS7 pkcs7 = fields.verifySignature(name,"BC");
```